# Hadoop Fairschduler doesn't utilize all map slots

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, scheduler

Running a 12-node hadoop cluster with total 48 map-slots available. Submitting bunch of jobs, but never see all map slots being utilized. Maximum number of busy slots is floating around 30-35, but never close to 48. Why?

Here's the configuration of fairscheduler.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<allocations>
  <pool name="big">
    <minMaps>10</minMaps>
    <minReduces>10</minReduces>
    <maxRunningJobs>3</maxRunningJobs>
  </pool>
  <pool name="medium">
    <minMaps>10</minMaps>
    <minReduces>10</minReduces>
    <maxRunningJobs>3</maxRunningJobs>
    <weight>3.0</weight>
  </pool>
  <pool name="small">
    <minMaps>20</minMaps>
    <minReduces>20</minReduces>
    <maxRunningJobs>20</maxRunningJobs>
    <weight>100.0</weight>
  </pool>
</allocations>
```

The idea is that jobs in small queue should always have a priority, the next important queue is 'medium' and the less important is 'big'. Sometimes I see jobs in medium or big queue starve although there are more map slots available that are not used.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the issue can be caused because the maxRunningJobs option is not taken into account while computing shares for jobs.  I think that parameter is handled after slots (from the exceeding job) has been already assigned to a tasktracker.  That is happening every n seconds from the UpdateThread.update()-> update Runability() method from FairScheduler class. I suppose that in your case after some time jobs from “medium” and “big” pool gets a bigger deficit than jobs from the “small” pool, that means that the next task will be scheduled from the job in medium or big pool. When the task is scheduled the restriction of maxRunningJobs take place and puts the exceeding jobs into a non runnable state. The same thing appears on the following update.

This is just my guess after looking after some source of fscheduler. If you can I would probably try to remove maxRunningJobs from the config and see how the scheduler behaves without that limitation and if it takes all of your slots..

Weigths for the pools in my oppinion seems to be to high. Weigh of 100 would mean that this pool should get 100x more slots than the default pool. I would try to lower this number by few factors if you want to have fair sharing between your pools. Otherwise jobs from others pools will be launched just when they will meet their deficit (it is calculated from the running tasks and minShare)

Another option why jobs are starving is maybe because of delay scheduling that is included in the fsched with the aim of improving computation locality? This can be probably improved by increasing a repclication factor  but I do not think this is your case..

[some docs on the fairscheduler..](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/MAPREDUCE-233/src/contrib/fairscheduler/designdoc/fair_scheduler_design_doc.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The starvation probably occurs because the priority of the small pool is really really high (2^100 more than big 2^97 more than medium). When all the jobs are are ordered by priority and you have waiting jobs in the small pool. The next job in that pool needs 20 slots and it has higher priority than anything else so the open slots just wait there until a currently running job will free them. there are no "unneeded slots" to divide to other priorities

see highlights from  [the implementation notes of the fair schedulere](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/fair_scheduler.html#Implementation):

> "The fair shares are calculated by **dividing the capacity of the
>   cluster among runnable jobs according to a "weight" for each job.** By
>   default the weight is based on priority, with **each level of priority
>   having 2x higher weight than the next** (for example, VERY_HIGH has 4x
>   the weight of NORMAL). However, weights can also be based on job sizes
>   and ages, as described in the Configuring section. For jobs that are
>   in a pool, fair shares also take into account the minimum guarantee
>   for that pool. This capacity is divided among the jobs in that pool
>   according again to their weights."
>
> Finally, when limits on a user's running jobs or a pool's running jobs
>   are in place, we choose which jobs get to run by sorting all jobs in
>   order of priority and then submit time, as in the standard Hadoop
>   scheduler. **Any jobs that fall after the user/pool's limit in this
>   ordering are queued up and wait idle until they can be run. During
>   this time, they are ignored from the fair sharing calculations and do
>   not gain or lose deficit (their fair share is set to zero).**

Comment: `The next job in that pool needs 20 slots and it has higher priority than anything else so the open slots just wait there until a currently running job will free them.` - If the Job requires 500 M slots, will 499 M slots be idle for another M slot to be a free? This is a poor design decision. I was thinking if a job requires 20 M slots and only 10 M slots are available, then the scheduler will allocate 10 M slots to that Job and as more M slots become free they will be allocated to the Job. All the M tasks need not be allocated to the Job at once. Why keep the slots idle? Correct me !!

Comment: The scheduler prioritize jobs but it is changed see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-4789  Also heres's a presentation on the scheduler http://www.slideshare.net/krzycube/the-hadoop-fair-scheduler. Also note that hadoop is designed for larger cluster and a min-pool of almost half the cluster with very high-priority is not a common setting

Comment: Still doesn't address why the cluster is not fully utilized as in the OP.

Comment: Jobs in the small queue always require max 1 map slot per job, so they never starve other queues although they have higher weight. I just wanted to make sure that jobs in small queue will ALWAYS get slots no matter what (since they don't require a lot anyway). What I'm seeing with 'big' and 'medium' queues is that although jobs are running they don't utilize all map slots that are available. Like a job is running and takes only 15 slots although there are more slots and no other jobs.

Comment: Ok now I got you - the number of maps is driven  by the number of DFS blocks that needs to be accessed and not just the number of slots currently available see http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces

Comment: I'm using mongo-hadoop plugin and mongo is sharded, so for most of the jobs the number of chunks (and therefore mappers) is about ~600. So there shouldn't be a problem with that. What I've figured is that when I killed one slave the utilization of cluster increased immediately. Before the number of mappers was floating around 30-35 (mostly 30) and now it's mostly around 40. Weird.